# React native object in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a state like this:

```
        "answers": {
            "1": {
                "name": "....",
                "order": "....",
                "text": "...,
                "type": "..."
            },
            "2": {
                "name": "...",
                "order": "...",
                "text": "....",
                "type": "..."
            },}
```

I need only names. I tried this.state.answers[0][1] but it doesnt work. how can ı select only names ?

Comment: "answers" should be array not object

Answer (score 1):

`Object.values(answers)` will gives you the values of the object as array.

`Object.values(ansers).map( a => a.name)` just take the names

Maybe learning JS basics, like [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) and [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) , could be better than skipping to jump into React.